# How To Measure Work Done Against Friction On A Non-Linear Path?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics, classical-mechanics, parametrization

I've been trying to solve how to find the Work done against friction as a ball rolls down a curve, but haven't been able to find anything matching what I want online. The solution I have came up with is the following:

$$
W_{\mu} = mg\mu\int_{a}^{b}{\frac{\underline{c}'(t)\cdot\underline{i}}{||\underline{c}'(t)||}dt}
$$

I derived this by first using the equation containing both $\cos(\theta)$ and the dot product of two vectors to find the $\cos(\theta)$ of the curve to the axis, as the normal force is $mg\cos(\theta)$.

I've verified that the formula works for a generalised linear slope, however I have not been able to verify it for all slopes.

Does this equation work? How would I go about verifying it for any general curve?

Comment: Can you try it on a simple nonlinear curve, say a parabola, such that you can get the work done in another way, to compare it to your method?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about calculating it in another way. I have tried on a parabola, getting an expression in terms of arcsinh, but I don't have a value to compare it to.

Comment: what is the meaning of symbols?

Comment: Mu is the coefficient of friction, c(t) is the parameterisation of the curve along which the object travels, and a and b are the boundaries for t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am obtaining a slightly different result for the work done by the force of friction on the rolling ball.

I'm assuming $c(t)=\left(x(t),y(t)\right):a\leq t \leq b$ is the parametric curve which describes the motion of the ball on the time domain $[a,b]$.

Recall that any (force) vector can be decomposed into two components: a *magnitude* and a *direction*.

The magnitude of the force of friction at any time $t$ is $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mu\times \left(\text{magnitude of normal force}\right)&=&\mu \times \Big\|\text{Proj}_{\left(-y'(t),x'(t)\right)}\Big((0,-mg)\Big)\Big\| \\ &=& \frac{\mu mg|x'(t)|}{\|c'(t)\|}\end{eqnarray*}$$

The direction of the force of friction opposes the direction of motion which in this case is $-\frac{c'(t)}{\|c'(t)\|}$.

So, at any time $t\in [a,b]$ the force of friction is given by $F_f=-\frac{\mu mg|x'(t)|}{\|c'(t)\|^2} c'(t)$

Hence the work is $$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{c\left([a,b]\right)}(F_f \cdot T)\mathrm{d}s&=&\int_a^b \left(-\frac{\mu mg|x'(t)|}{\|c'(t)\|^2} c'(t)\cdot \frac{c'(t)}{\|c'(t)\|}\right)\|c'(t)\|\mathrm{d}t \\ &=& -\mu mg\int_a^b |x'(t)|\mathrm{d}t\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: When I applied your solution to a linear slope at an angle of theta to the horizontal, (parameterisation (t, tan(theta) * t), I got a Work against friction of -mg mu s sec(theta), when the actual result should be -mg mu s cos(theta), which is what was obtained from my formula (and the standard method of finding the Normal force).

Comment: I did make a mistake; the direction of motion of the ball is actually $-\frac{c'(t)}{\|c'(t)\|}$, not $c'(t)$. To respond to your comment, if a ball is rolling down a linear slope of angle $\theta$, the parametric curve $c(t)$ that describes the ball's motion will likely be something different from $c(t)=(t,\tan(\theta)t)$. In order to find the trajectory of the ball you would have to solve a differential equation that's been derived from Newton's second law of motion.

Comment: My comment was more to say that, for some specific parameterisation that we can find the work done for, your equation doesn't hold. I don't think mine holds for more general curves. I saw an interesting answer on the physics stack exchange that says that the total work against friction is just the horizontal distance travelled. I think this makes sense as you could approximate a curve using straight lines, and indeed the work would be the sum of their horizontal lengths (Lcos(theta)mg mu). If you take the limit of this approximation, I believe it still holds, as you said in your correction.

Comment: Note that the horizontal distance travelled by the ball is $\int_a^b|x'(t)|\mathrm{d}t$ which gives me some faith in my result as it is in more accordance with what you saw on Physics SE. I always like to proceed with extreme cation when I parameterize curves. For example, the parametric curve $(t,\tan(\theta)t)$ cannot represent a ball moving *downhill* if $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ as it necessarily describes a ball moving *uphill* along the line $y=\tan(\theta)x$

Comment: That is true, although work done against friction rolling down is the same as the work done against friction when it is travelling up.